# Example for Azure Alert create using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I am trying to create Azure Alert using Python SDK and Below is the code

```
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.monitor.models import RuleMetricDataSource
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.monitor.models import ThresholdRuleCondition
from azure.mgmt.monitor.models import RuleEmailAction


subscription_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
resource_group_name = 'example-rg'
vm_name = 'example_vm'

# Set up the credentials
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()


resource_id = (
    "subscriptions/{}/"
    "resourceGroups/{}/"
    "providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{}"
).format(subscription_id, resource_group_name, vm_name)

# create client
client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

# I need a subclass of "RuleDataSource"
data_source = RuleMetricDataSource(
    resource_uri=resource_id,
    metric_name='Percentage CPU'
)


# I need a subclasses of "RuleCondition"
rule_condition = ThresholdRuleCondition(
    data_source=data_source,
    operator='GreaterThanOrEqual',
    threshold=90,
    window_size='PT5M',
    time_aggregation='Average'
)

# I need a subclass of "RuleAction"
rule_action = RuleEmailAction(
    send_to_service_owners=True,
    custom_emails=[
        'abc@gmail.com'
    ]
)

rule_name = 'MyPyTestAlertRule'
my_alert = client.alert_rules.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    rule_name,
    {
        'location': 'North Central US',
        'alert_rule_resource_name': rule_name,
        'description': 'Testing Alert rule creation',
        'is_enabled': True,
        'condition': rule_condition,
        'actions': [
            rule_action
        ]
    }
)
```

Unfortunately I am getting below error, difficult find any valid example code  in the website. It would be really great if somebody provides a example to create Azure alert using python SDK.

As per error it classic alert rules based on this metric is no longer supported.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/test/alert/test.py", line 71, in <module>
    my_alert = monitor_client.alert_rules.create_or_update(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/monitor/v2016_03_01/operations/_alert_rules_operations.py", line 370, in create_or_update
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Creating or editing classic alert rules based on this metric is no longer supported. To learn about new alert rules see https://aka.ms/create-metric-alerts
Code: BadRequest
Message: Creating or editing classic alert rules based on this metric is no longer supported. To learn about new alert rules see https://aka.ms/create-metric-alerts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

I have used `azure.mgmt.monitor` from package `azure-mgmt-monitor`

For Reference check this [document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/monitor/manage_metric_alerts.py).

##### My Code:

**`app.py`:**

```py
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
sub_id= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
resource_group = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = MonitorManagementClient(credential=credentials,subscription_id=sub_id)


Alert = client.metric_alerts.create_or_update(resource_group,
        "Metric_alert_",
        {
          "location": "global",
          "description": "This is the description of the rule1",
          "severity": "3",
          "enabled": True,
          "scopes": [
            f"/subscriptions/{sub_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm"
          ],
          "evaluation_frequency": "PT1M",
          "window_size": "PT15M",
          "target_resource_type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "target_resource_region": "Australiaeast",            #VM's region
          "criteria": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
            "all_of": [
              {
                "criterion_type": "DynamicThresholdCriterion",
                "name": "High_CPU_80",
                "metric_name": "Percentage CPU",
                "metric_namespace": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines",
                "operator": "GreaterOrLessThan",
                "time_aggregation": "Average",
                "dimensions": [],
                "alert_sensitivity": "Medium",
                "failing_periods": {
                  "number_of_evaluation_periods": "4",
                  "min_failing_periods_to_alert": "4"
                },
              }
            ]
          },
          "auto_mitigate": False,
          "actions": [
          ]
        }
    )

print("Alert created Successfully.")
```

##### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is worked like charm, where do find he examples the code?

Comment: From Azure sample repository. I have added the reference document in answer. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/monitor/manage_metric_alerts.py